# How to configure my own SMTP server in my system?

Tags: smtp

I am in a position to configure my own SMTP server in my system. I have an internet connection in my system as well. My task is to create my own SMTP server and I have configured those SMTP details in client like thunderbird etc. and can it should be able to send mail to users who have accounts in gmail,yahoo etc. For example if i create a domain name www.mycompany.com in my SMTP and if I created the user name as john, I need to be able to send the mail from john@mycompany.com to any gmail,yahoo users. Also I need to receive email vice versa. What are the procedures?

Comment: The main problem using your PC as Mailserer is that if your IP doesn't belong to your domain (reverse lookup "PTR") many mail service didn't accept your mail. I think there are also spam filters which check for dynamic ip ranges.

Comment: Is this still the case? What would you currently advise to allow sending email from my registered domain name?

Comment: exactly , usually on pc that happens